# Consulta mySQL retornando em branco

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz a seguinte seleção

```
$selficha = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT  * FROM ficha WHERE nome='$user->username'");

$ficha = mysqli_fetch_row($selficha);
```

Quando quero pegar um resultado da tabela `ficha` não aparece nada.
Eu dou `print $ficha["deus"]` e o resultado fica em branco.

### Estrutura da tabela `ficha`

```
CREATE TABLE `ficha` (
  `nome` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `força1` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `força2` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `const` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `agil` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Crenca` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Dedi` smallint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hp` smallint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hpa` smallint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cosmo` smallint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cosmoa` smallint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `golpe1` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `golpe2` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `golpe3` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `golpe4` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regiao` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `grupo` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `convite` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `deus` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cea` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `v` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

Comment: O retorno de `mysqli_fetch_row` é um *array* de índices numéricos, não um *array* associativo.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo que você **sempre** leia a documentação das funções antes de utilizá-las. Caso contrário você programará na base de tentativa e erro, se frustando e perdendo tempo.

> [**mysqli_fetch_row**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)
>
> mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Obtém uma linha do resultado como uma matriz numerada

Ou seja, o retorno será um *array* de índices numéricos, não um *array* associativo. Assim, para você acessar o valor da coluna `"deus"`, precisará acessar `$ficha[18]`, visto que a coluna é a 19a na tabela.

Você pode utilizar a `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

> [**mysqli_fetch_assoc**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
>
> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Obtem uma linha do conjunto de resultados como uma matriz associativa

E, agora sim, poderá fazer `$ficha['deus']`, pois o retorno será um *array* associativo.

Você pode utilizar a `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

> [**mysqli_fetch_object**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)
>
> mysqli_fetch_object -- result->fetch_object — Retorna a linha atual do conjunto de resultados como um objeto

Assim poderá fazer `$ficha->deus`, pois o retorno será um objeto, instância de `stdClass`.

Você pode utilizar a `mysqli_fetch_array`

> [**mysqli_fetch_array**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
>
> mysqli_fetch_array -- result->fetch_array — Obtem uma linha do resultado como uma matriz associativa, numérica, ou ambas

Assim poderá escolher se deseja um *array* de índices numéricos, um *array* associativos ou ambos:

- `mysqli_fetch_array($selficha, MYSQLI_NUM)`, mesmo que `mysqli_fetch_row`;
- `mysqli_fetch_array($selficha, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`, mesmo que `mysqli_fetch_assoc`;
- `mysqli_fetch_array($selficha, MYSQLI_BOTH)`, une os dois resultados acima;
- `mysqli_fetch_array($selficha)`, mesmo que quando definido `MYSQLI_BOTH`.